# LOAD DATA mysql command and use only one column

Tags: mysql

I have table t1 with three columns, and a file per line a text.
my tables contains id,sura and aya fields. I need to fill only aya from File. 
I use the following command:
`load data infile '/home/mohsen/codes/haq/translation-tmp/fa.ghomshei.txt' into table tr_fa_ghomshei LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ;`

**Now question is :** 
How can I limit to `aya` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
load data infile '/home/mohsen/codes/haq/translation-tmp/fa.ghomshei.txt'
    into table tr_fa_ghomshei
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (@id, @sura, aya) ;
```

Then simply ignore @id and @sura.

But... Are you loading into a table with only one column?  If the table has multiple columns, this won't work, and you need to explain what are really doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :
`load data infile '/home/mohsen/codes/haq/translation-tmp/fa.ghomshei.txt' into table tr_fa_ghomshei LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (aya);`